# How to set up database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up ruby on rails to develop locally on a 64 bit windows 7 machine using SQL server 2005.  We have an existing database and it does not conform to the ruby way so I created a table to test conectivity.

Unable to find information on properly configuring the database.yml file I suspect my problem is there.  I have both 32-bit and 64-bit DSNs defined.  When I run the console I get "Table doesn't exist"

Here's my database.yml.  I don't know

```
default: &default
  host: 111.222.333.444
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: DSN_Name
  database: ERP
  username: sa
  password:  ********


development:
  <<: *default
  host: 111.222.333.444
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: DSN_Name
  database: ERP
  username: sa
  password: ********

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Does anyone know how the default works?  I can't find any information on it.  Specifically "<<: *default"

I updated my database.yml file.  Created a table for testing; used the plural and ID for the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Created a model
    class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

But I get "Table doesn't exist" after connecting to Car and entering 'Car'.  Anyone have any idea what the next step would be to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&default` in the line `default: &default`, means make the key/value pairs under this YAML namespace available as the variable `*default`.

The `<<: *default` lines are taking those key/value pairs, and making them part of the other groups, so you only need to change values that are different from the `default:` group.

If all your databases are on the same machine, then your `database.yml` should look a lot like this:

```
default: &default
  host: 111.222.333.444
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: DSN_Name
  username: sa
  password: ********

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ERP_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: ERP_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ERP_production
```

Since you are on sqlserver, you'll probably have to create all those databases yourself (instead of letting Rails do it for you).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is extremely helpful.  All those databases already exist so I'm good there.  I tried to access a table I made for testing but I can not.  I created a model do I have to do anything else?  I updated my post.  I can make a new thread if needed.

Comment: @Joe The model should be named as the singular of your table, so if your test table is named 'orders', then your model should be `app/models/order.rb`, and look like this: `class Order < ActiveRecord::Base; end`.  If the class name doesn't quite match the table name, add this inside the model: `self.table_name = 'tblOrders'` (with the actual name of your table).

Comment: The problem was capitalization.  I made everything lowercase in the test table and I was able to connect.  I received Car(id: integer, cars_name: string)

Answer (score -1):

from:   https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

> Force Schema To Lowercase
>
> Although it is not necessary, the Ruby convention is to use lowercase
>   method names. If your database schema is in upper or mixed case, we
>   can force all table and column names during the schema reflection
>   process to be lowercase. Add this to your config/initializers file for
>   the adapter.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true
```

> Schemas & Users
>
> Depending on your user and schema setup, it may be needed to use a
>   table name prefix of dbo.. So something like this in your initializer
>   file for ActiveRecord or the adapter.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = 'dbo.'
```

Comment: Don't know what the link is for.  Do you want me to modify the ActiveRecord module?  And if so which one?  I also checked every file in the config/initializers folder and there isn't any ActiveRecord class nor SQLServerAdapter.  Do I need to create one?

Comment: My database is mixed case and I think that is the issue.  Making the test table and fields all lower case fixed it.  If you can tell me where to put "lowercase_schema_reflection = true" I think that will help a great deal.

Comment: Just create a new initializer that includes those lines to initialize active record with those options.

Comment: I followed your instructions but it did not work.  There is still something else wrong.  I suspect the second line is not needed since my 'Car' table shows up in mangement studio as 'dbo.Car but I can connect fine to that.  I think it may be time to start a new thread.  Thanks anyway.